# linkedserver SQL/ORACLE - An error occurred while preparing a query for execution

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-server

my problem is the same... i have this code that is use in my db utils class for make query.

```
    public DataSet sqlCommandSelect(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
            string strOrders = command
            SqlCommand objOrderCommand = new SqlCommand(strOrders, myConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter objOrdAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            objOrdAdapter.SelectCommand = objOrderCommand;
            objOrdAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
            objOrderCommand.Dispose();
            objOrdAdapter.Dispose();
            return objDataSet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("sqlCommandSelect : " + command + " " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now i am trying to make this query (that work greats on sql editor)

```
        SELECT * FROM 
        OPENQUERY(ORACDGMI,'SELECT * FROM CIC.ANAGRAFICA ')
```

ORACDGMI Is a linkedserver SQL/ORACLE

Give me the error:

```
        An error occurred while preparing a query for execution
```

Any suggestion?